# MacBook is attacked but can't find any threats

Tags: macbook-pro, security, virus, scanning

Recently, I was installing an unofficial software on my mac. It's a mistake, I know, but I was so confident that I can register if something is going wrong.

Coming to the point, I give the permission to run from an unidentified developer and start the installation. However, I did noticed that the installation is weird, you can tell with a little bit of experience, so I stoped it immediately, but it was too late. My mac is going too slow, even when I'm just browsing the internet and not doing any hard work, it's getting overheated and I also noticed that the battery is wasted significantly fast, even on sleep mode. So, I'm pretty sure that there is some sort of viruses running in the background.

I did tried several antivirus programs, malware scanners etc. but it all says the same "No viruses or malware found". Really don't know what to do, anyone have suggestions for advanced scanners or something like that? Just without formatting the device please.

Here is a screenshot from my Activity Monitor:
[image]
[image]

Comment: i assume you've tried MalwareBytes?

Comment: @jmh yes! I did.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot from Activity Monitor showing the applications using most CPU time? Also, what did you download and from where?

Comment: Is this from a moment where your system felt slow? Neither CPU nor Memory show any pressure at all on these screenshots.

Comment: What model of Mac is this? Does it have a mechanical hard drive?

Comment: @nohillside no, actually right now, the system is running just fine. I will follow Activity Monitor and update the screenshots, when it happen again.

Comment: @benwiggy It's a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) 256GB, no it's an SSD

Comment: I don't know what's 'normal' for Google Chrome, but I'd be worried by all those Chrome processes.  Might be worth quitting Chrome and trying another browser, then seeing if things are better. (Or make sure Chrome is up to date.) You could try quitting Steam as well.

Comment: @benwiggy The more tabs one has open the more processes Chrome runs (as do other browsers). And the system shows no sign of being under heavy load so quitting Steam or closing browser tabs isn't necessary.

Comment: I don't know, but it can't be that the machine is slowing itself down accidentally right after installing a particular software. Anyway, I can tell that there is not a clear answer for my question. So, I will just pick @benwiggy 's answer as the right one, because it's, in my opinion, the clearest and closest one. And will continue following the CPU and memory usage, so if I catch anything unusual, I will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Going slow" is not really an indicator of malware. Most malware can do its job without using significant CPU, and malware designers want their software to be unnoticed.

If several malware apps have said "it's not malware", then that's probably true.

It's much more likely that there are other problems with your Mac. Check Activity Monitor, and see what is using excessive CPU. Remove third-party Launch Agents or any other software that runs in the background. Test a new user account, and see if that it better. If so: it's a user account problem.

Make sure you have low memory pressure (also in Activity Monitor), and that you have plenty of free disk space.

Answer (score -1):

Try [*Clean My Mac*](https://macpaw.com/cleanmymac). It checks for viruses and deletes them, as well as uninstalls any unnecessary files. It can also act as an app uninstaller, making sure every file and folder related only to that app is deleted. It generally removes about 3 gigabytes a week from my main computer, and it hasn't deleted any thing I haven't wanted it to yet. The only downside is that it cost $40 to get a key, but it is totally worth it if you are using your Mac as your primary computer. It mainly deletes outdated stuff, but it allows you to choose what to and what not to delete. It does not constantly monitor your system, it just scans it when you open the app and tell it to. It lets you see what you are deleting just in case you don't want to delete anything.

[image: yeet]

Comment: I tried it now. Yes it did find 4 threats, but I have to buy a license for 40$ so I can delete them. It didn't even provide information, what threats is founded. So, I'm not pretty sure if this is the best solution!

Comment: There is a popular anti-virus code called Total AV. It has a free download but will pepper you initially to buy it. I'm running it now and i'll let you know how it works.

Comment: @Hussein yeah, sorry about that :) I bought it a while ago and use it all the time. I would consider it.

Comment: @jmh Thanks, waiting for your respond

Comment: 3 Gb a day.....? Sounds like it's just emptying cache data, which then has to get rebuilt, only to get deleted the next day.

Comment: @benwiggy you would think so, but I haven't experienced any side effects of cache deletion. I should have made myself clearer. I said "per day" but I meant "per run" which is about every week or so. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: If you don't know what it's deleting, then you can't really say whether it's beneficial or not. I'm generally wary of apps that monitor your system, which are by and large unnecessary.

Comment: Total AV requires you to purchase the software so i couldn't complete my test. I didn't want to buy it at $30.00